# How to retrieve properties for an Active Directory user using DirectorySearcher in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ldap, directorysearcher

I am trying to retrieve the email address for a known Active Directory user by using their login ID and the DirectorySearcher.FindOne() method in VB.Net but I have been unable to get any results.

Sorry but I am new to VB.Net and do not know where I am going wrong. I have tried using various examples that I have found on the net but they all are in C#. I have been able to convert the code to VB but I am still not able to pull results using what I have found. In the latest example I found [here](http://technico.qnownow.com/how-retrieve-active-directory-user-properties-using-ldap/)! it is using the FindAll() method and putting the results in a SearchResultCollection object. The collection ended up with a count of 0 so I have tried using the FindOne() method and tried to put the result in a SearchResult object. This didn't work for me either.

```
Public Shared Sub RetrieveUser(ByVal username As String)
        Dim propUsername As String = "samaccountname"
        Dim propFirstName As String = "givenName"
        Dim propLastName As String = "sn"
        Dim propDisplayName As String = "cn"
        Dim propMail As String = "mail"
        Dim propGuid As String = "objectguid"
        Dim results As SearchResultCollection
        Dim result As SearchResult
        Dim directoryEntry As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry("LDAP_PATH", "DOMIAIN\USERNAME", "PASSWORD", AuthenticationTypes.ServerBind)

        Using directorySearcher As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry)
            directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(propUsername)
            directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(propDisplayName)
            directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(propFirstName)
            directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(propLastName)
            directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(propMail)
            directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(propGuid)
            directorySearcher.Filter = String.Format("({0})", "&(objectClass=user)(cn=" & username & ")")
            directorySearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree
            '    directorySearcher.SearchRoot.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure
            directorySearcher.PageSize = 100

            'results = directorySearcher.FindAll()
            result = directorySearcher.FindOne()

            'For Each result In results

            If result.Properties.Contains(propUsername) Then
                Console.WriteLine("User Name: " & result.Properties(propUsername)(0))
            End If

            If result.Properties.Contains(propGuid) Then
                    Console.WriteLine("User GUID: " & BitConverter.ToString(CType(result.Properties(propGuid)(0), Byte())).Replace("-", String.Empty))
                End If

                If result.Properties.Contains(propMail) Then
                    Console.WriteLine("Mail ID: " & result.Properties(propMail)(0))
                End If

                If result.Properties.Contains(propDisplayName) Then
                    Console.WriteLine("DisplayName: " & result.Properties(propDisplayName)(0))
                End If
            'Next


            directorySearcher.Dispose()
            directoryEntry.Dispose()
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: Are you certain the 'cn' attribute contains the user ID? I usually use sAMAccountName when searching Active Directory for users by logon ID.

Comment: No. I'm not sure about that. I was going off of the example I found. I am not very clear on the use of cn so I might not be using it correctly also. How can I know?

Comment: If you've got an LDAP browser, you can look at an account to see what's where. [MS's LDP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2693643/remote-server-administration-tools-rsat-for-windows-operating-systems) is a good one to use with Active Directory, specifically, because you don't need to know much about the domain. Most DCs will have host records for themselves on the domain, so you can use your domain name as the host under connection-connect. Connection-bind you can use 'currently logged on user' provided you're logged into the domain.

Comment: Then view-tree & leave the baseDN blank will show you the root of your domain. *usually* user accounts are somewhere obvious -- cn=users is the default, but a lot of admins will make an OU for users. You can right-click the root of the domain, select search, and then search for something vague like (&(objectClass=person)) to get a list of accounts. If you recognize one, copy the "DN" and then use *that* as the base dn in view-tree. In AD, the logon name is almost always sAMAccountName, and userPrincipalName is logonid@<domain> so sAMAccountName is a good bet when searching for user IDs.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't think I'll have the permission to install the mentioned software but I'll give the samaccountname a try and report back with my findings. It's going to be a while with the holidays and all but thanks again!

Comment: LisaJ thank you so much for your help. Once I replaced the cn with the sAMAccountName, I started getting the expected result!